# If the sum of sets is open then one of them is open?

Tags: real-analysis, sumset

I have managed to prove that if one of two subsets $A$ and $B$ is open, then $A+B$ is open.
The next question is:

If $A+B$ is open, is it (always) true that either $A$ or $B$ is open (or both)?

For clarity:

$$ A+B = \{ a+b \mid a\in A, b\in B \} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A=[0,\infty)$ and $B=(-\infty,0]$. Then $A+B = \mathbb{R}$ which is open (and closed), but neither $A$ nor $B$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

No,

consider $A=\mathbb Q$ and $B=(\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q)\cup\{0\}$. Then $A+B=\mathbb R$ but none of $A,B$ is open.

Comment: and both $A,B$ have no interior

Comment: That was also my first thought. But the sum of a rational and an irrational number is always irrational, so  $A + B = B \ne \mathbb R$.

Comment: ok, I misunderstud the definition of $A+B$, but then it suffices to add $0$ to $B$

Comment: b.t.w here is a nice exercice: show that if $\mu(A)>0$ then $A-A$ contains a neighborhood of $0$.